# Exact closed form solution to the quantum harmonic oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, harmonic-oscillator

I came across this question in Griffiths QM, which asked to show that this equation

$$\Psi(x,t)=\left(\frac{m\omega}{\pi \hbar}\right)^{1/4} \exp\left[-\frac{m\omega}{2\hbar} \left(x^2+\frac{a^2}{2}(1+e^{-2i\omega t})+\frac{i\hbar t}{m}-2axe^{-i\omega t}\right)\right]$$

$a$ is any real constant

satisfies the time-*dependent* Schrodinger's equation for a harmonic potential

I was able to show this (simple substitution), I know the ladder and the  brute-force solutions to the SE for a harmonic potential, but I'm interested in knowing how the equation was obtained, I tried Google but didn't find any resource related to this.

Any hints or concepts on how this equation is derived would be helpful

Comment: Wow, there's no typo in that equation? Can you give the page number and edition number?

Comment: Page - 70, Chapter 2, problem-2.45, Its a 1994 edition. (It also said that the equation was discovered by Schrodinger himself)

Comment: *how it was obtained...* if he didn't list a reference for the wave function, I imagine he might've just come up with a mathematical expression that did (or didn't) satisfy the TDSE.

Comment: Possible, But the equation doesn't look easy and definitely not obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note the following: If $\psi(x,0)$ is *any* normalizable wave-function in your Hilbert space, then $\psi(x,t) = e^{-iHt} \psi(x,0)$ (I've set $\hbar = 1$) satisfies the time-dependent Schrodinger equation (we call this "time evolution"). This can be seen by using the fact that the stationary states form a basis for your Hilbert space and so $\psi(x,0)$ can be expanded in terms of them. One can then check by substitution (after plugging in the expanded form of $\psi(x,0)$ into $\psi(x,t)$) that the TDSE is satisfied.

Now I haven't checked this explicitly, but to me this seems like the time evolved wave function for the ground state shifted to the right by $a$ (this has the right properties at $a=0$ and $t=0$). Namely, we simply apply the time evolution operator to $\psi(x,0) = \psi_0(x-a)$ where $\psi_0(x)$ is the ground state wave function. To actually verify that $\psi(x,t) = e^{-iHt}\psi(x,0)$ coincides with the wave function you write, one can proceed as follows:

Use $$\psi(x,t) = e^{-iHt}\psi(x,0) = \int dy \,K(x,y,t)\psi(y,0),$$ where $K(x,y,t)$ is the quantum mechanical propagator for the harmonic oscillator for which the explicit expression can be found on this [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagator#Basic_examples:_propagator_of_free_particle_and_harmonic_oscillator). Perform the subsequent Gaussian integral. If I'm right you'll end up with exactly the wave function that you want.

In short, finding the most general time-dependent solution boils down to finding the propagator. One can then use that to time evolve any stationary wave function that one wishes.

Answer (score 0):

This is the wavefunction of a [**coherent state**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_states); it is a well-known solution of the quantum harmonic oscillator and it has a large number of nice properties. There is a good number of independent ways to derive it so it is pretty pointless to try and guess which one Griffiths was thinking of.